# while creating a Yml file from sonarqube to github its failed?

Tags: github, sonarqube, github-actions, sonarqube-scan

I created github organization and integrated with sonarqube generated tokens from sonarqube to acces the dotnet github projects. When i tried to place the Yml file the build is faild.
This is my build.yml file

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master


jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11
      - name: Cache SonarQube packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~\sonar\cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache SonarQube scanner
        id: cache-sonar-scanner
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: .\.sonar\scanner
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar-scanner
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar-scanner
      - name: Install SonarQube scanner
        if: steps.cache-sonar-scanner.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          New-Item -Path .\.sonar\scanner -ItemType Directory
          dotnet tool update dotnet-sonarscanner --tool-path .\.sonar\scanner
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
        shell: powershell
        run: |
          .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner begin /k:"nivethasivanandan_validationrepo_AY2JvRWJcKpBpqbipHhf" /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}" /d:sonar.host.url="${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}"
          dotnet build
          .\.sonar\scanner\dotnet-sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}"
```

i received error as

```
Build
The following actions uses node12 which is deprecated and will be forced to run on node16: actions/checkout@v2, actions/setup-java@v1, actions/cache@v1. For more info: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-06-13-github-actions-all-actions-will-run-on-node16-instead-of-node12-by-default/ Build
Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/checkout@v2, actions/setup-java@v1, actions/cache@v1. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/. 
Build
Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I am using java version 17. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You're using old versions of these actions, but the error is in the build step. Notice that there's a dedicated action for Sonar scans: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action